# Postpone Apple push notification approval from startup

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to postpone the first time app startup request, about allowing apple push notifications: "X would like to send you push notifications" ("Don't Allow / OK")

I seems to remember having see apps before, where the request first popped-up after a pre conditional action. Is it possible to postpone the request from startup to a time where the user has done a pre conditional action, and the user then knows why they should/shouldn't allow push notifications for this app?

It is also regarding the thought that most people would reject it, if it is the first thing that pops up after they opened an app for the first time, and they have no idea why the should allow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notifTypes];
```

when you want the user to enable push for your app.

That's when the popup will show.

Comment: Thanks - and I didn't even take the time to look in the first part of my AppDelegate - where I manually calls it...